# How to stop a GCD dispatch _after block from returning the result.May be silly

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am a swift learner.I am working on a project where i am using a `dispatch_after` GCD command nested inside a `NSTimer` function.Other parts of the code performs several iterations one of which is to `invalidate` the timer. I am successful in invalidating the timer.But even after invalidating the timer the `dispatch_ after` block executes once. That response has become a bug in my project.So i would like to know that is there any way or method to block or terminate the the `dispatch_after` method at its waiting state similar like `Invalidate` method for Stopping the `NSTimer`. Sorry if i am silly

```
timer2=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(t.a+t.b), target: self, selector: "updateSequential:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
//This is the call for NSTimer.
var f = 0
func updateSequential(timer2:NSTimer)
{
    var x = self.f                                           //Setting the Initial value for sequential order
    self.noDispLabel.text = String(x+1)
    print("\(x)")
    var content=self.imageArray[x]

    self.imageDisp.image=nil
    self.titleDispLabel.text=nil
    self.progressBar.setProgress(5.0, animated: true)

    var delay =  5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            if(self.timer2 != nil)
            {
                self.imageDisp.image=UIImage(named:content.imageName)
                self.titleDispLabel.text=content.imageTitle
                self.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
            }
    }

    if( self.f < 4)                                     //Increment based on the condition
    {
        self.f++
    }
    else
    {
        self.f = 0
    }
    if(self.q==0)   // q is a global key variable referenced to invalidate the timer.
    {

        self.timer2=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8.0, target: self, selector: "updateSequential:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
    else
    {

        [timer2.invalidate]
        self.timer2 = nil
    }
}
```

Here the dispatch_after block must be invalidated along with the NSTimer invalidate.

Comment: @kientux I added the code as u asked. But i actually wanted to know that is there any method like Invalidate to terminate a dispatch block??.Thanks for showing interest in my question.

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure `self.timer2 = nil` is called? If yes and those code below `dispatch_after` doesn't take longer than 5 seconds (probably obvious), then the block in `dispatch_after` won't get called.

Comment: @kientux Actually my code works pretty well for the time being but i would like to know that is there any predefined methods to terminate the dispatch block to optimise my code for better performance.

Comment: after you dispatch a block for execution, there is no chance to to get it out from the queue.  what the block will do, is up to the code inside the block.

Comment: GCD doesn't have cancelation, if you want cancelation you can take a look at [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/), which is built on top of GCD plus some extra methods.

Comment: @kientux Thanks for the help. I'll look up at NSOperations.

Comment: @user3441734 Thanks for letting me know the facts.

Comment: Krishna, the queued block will be responsible for early return even though you are going to use NSOperation

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
    dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    XYZBlockResponse *response = [[XYZBlockResponse alloc] init];

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        if (!response.cancelBlock)
            NSLog(@"XYXBlock executed");
        else
            NSLog(@"XYXBlock did not execute");
    });
    response.cancelBlock = YES; // Set YES or NO.
```

XYZBlockResponse class is simple...

```
@interface XYZBlockResponse : NSObject
@property (assign) BOOL cancelBlock;
@end
```

Comment: could you please explain on your answer. Sorry but i am a learner and i could not get a grip of your logic.